# What causes the "Human Verification"?

Tags: support, captcha

l'm just experiencing the Human Verification now, and I can't find the captcha to solve.
What kinds of questions and answers can cause it?

Not all questions caused it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide) - the thresholds for captchas are listed out in that post.

Comment: I’ve noticed any time I start to write up a question, but then don’t post it until several hours later, I will always see the Captcha.

Comment: @pacoverflow https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333673/has-the-maximum-time-threshold-for-question-captchas-been-reintroduced-recently

Comment: @pacoverflow I don't know why.

Comment: Why 　is it "marked"  ?