# Has the maximum time threshold for question CAPTCHAs been reintroduced recently?

Tags: support, captcha, time-limit

I've noticed that when I take a long time to write up a question, and don't submit until the next day or later, I get prompted with a CAPTCHA.

After some searching, I found that [there used to be a 40-minute time limit for asking questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2293/377214) after which a CAPTCHA would appear, but [apparently this was removed in 2010](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38008/eliminate-the-captcha-on-long-questions-answers/38232#38232).

Many years later, today, it seems to have been reintroduced, but I cannot find any official posts regarding the topic since that 2010 removal.

If it was, when and why was it reintroduced, and what is the new time limit? (Or is it possible that the 2010 change never actually took place?)

Comment: I've been hitting it for years... so... ?

Comment: Is this only for questions, or also including answers? Because I've also been hitting this many times on Anime.SE where I left my tabs with an answer draft for a week or more... (Basically, after I was disconnected from the internet, then posting the answer after reconnecting for a long time)