# Unattractive design of CAPTCHA window on Russian Stack Overflow

Tags: support, bug, design, captcha

Once I was writing an answer on [Russian Stack Overflow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/) I got a CAPTCHA window that suggests clicking a tick to confirm your humanity:

[image]

> **Text translation:**
> Confirm you are not a robot
> Are you a real person? We apologise for an occurred confusion but we cannot determine it exactly whether you are a human being or a robot. Please, do not take it personally, bots and scripts can be extremely realistic nowadays!
>  Click a CAPTCHA tick and we will not interfere with you anymore.

I have asked a [question](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11399/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0) on META (Russian as well) about the design of this window. I consider it absolutely inappropriate. I recap it briefly:

1. The picture on left does not make any sense. What a strange robot is it, what is AR·TUR, why is the text on box not in Russian, even not in English (as I can see it)?
2. The text sticks to the picture. Two pixels more and it will get on the picture.
3. There is no SO or ruSO logotype. Consequently there is no acknowledgement that this is a SO's request, not fraudulent.

I could not find a similar window on English SO, but I am sure it exists. Is this design only a problem for Russian Stack Overflow? Is everything all right here (on enSO), and this bug should be fixed locally? Or does this bug takes place here, too, and should be fixed by *higher authorities*, i.e. enSO staff?

Comment: The point of CAPTCHAs is to make sure you are not a robot. It shows a picture of a robot for fun. It doesn't matter that the box the robot comes in is in a different language; it's not meant to be read; it's just a picture of a robot.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Yes, but it is not beautiful. IMHO, at least corners could have been rounded. Or just a better picture could have been found. Like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348240/do-not-repeatedly-require-trusted-contributors-to-solve-captchas-when-they-attem):) This one is more... like... soft and smooth. A dead robot as a result of human verification :)

Comment: It exists, oftentimes pops up to me when an answer contains a lot of code. The image is generic, albeit nicely integrated. That said, I think this picture is fun (just like waffles on the "post deleted" page), seems like a Brazilian [robot toy from the 80s](https://alphadrome.net/data/displayimage.php?album=1&pid=2953). It could use some extra `margin-right`, though.

Comment: I think it could be a little to the left. Also, captchas don't ask you to confirm your humanity, do they? They check if you are a human.

Comment: I'm so tired of rounded corners... I think I've typed `border-radius` too many times :).

Comment: @10Rep For me, as for non-English speaker, confirming humanity and confirming being a human are the same, sorry:) You can edit the question

Comment: @МаксимФисман I cannot edit the question unfortunately as there is another edit pending and I do not have edit privileges. It's not a big deal :)

Comment: Does the captcha look right on the test page: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/captcha or does it have same missing margins? It looks right for me and I'm on Chrome, on Win10 box.

Comment: @rene - looks about right to me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uK5h.png

Comment: Okay @OlegValter thanks. I expect that captcha route gets loaded in a div at some moment and then it gets messed up due to a missing css rule. I hardly ever trigger a captcha so I can't diagnose this any further.

Comment: @rene most likely (or an applied additional one). Agreed nothing more to do here, at least we have a desired and actual behavior confirmed. Максим Фисман - if you come across this on SOru, please, check out the markup.